# How do I pass half to a vertex shader?

Tags: c++, directx-11, hlsl, half-precision-float

The [`D3D11 Input Element Description`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/d3d10/ns-d3d10-d3d10_input_element_desc) has a field that specifies the format.

How can I pass `half`s (e.g. `DXGI_FORMAT_R16_FLOAT`) to the Input assembler when we have `float` (i.e. 32 bit fp) only on the CPU side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The half-precision format used by Direct3D is pretty standard these days.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format

The [DirectXMath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxmath/directxmath-portal) library has built-in functions for converting to/from half-precision:

- [XMHALF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxmath/half-data-type) and XMConvertHalfToFloat and XMConvertFloatToHalf
- [XMHALF2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/directxpackedvector/ns-directxpackedvector-xmhalf2) and the Load/Store functions for it.
- [XMHALF4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/directxpackedvector/ns-directxpackedvector-xmhalf4) and the Load/Store functions for it.

> There is also a F16C (also known as CVT16) intrinsic for doing the conversions, but you can really only count on them with systems that support AVX2 (or fixed platforms like Xbox One which has AVX but also F16C). See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/directxmath-f16c-and-fma/) for more details.